# RDBMS Resource Usage when Using PrestoDB

Tags: mysql, presto, presto-jdbc

When we querying mysql database using presto, is it means that we still using mysql’s resource like cpu or ram or not?. Thank you

Comment: Please share more details, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This from the faq explain your question

> If the Presto process is mostly idle, this means that Presto can not retrieve data fast enough from the HDFS data node. This could be caused by network or disk bandwidth or CPU on the data node.

As you see presto is a separate process that waits that the database sends the requested data. so the database has to "work" as normal

Comment: I see. Thank you bro @nbk